# Unable to saveEventually on a ParseUser with dirty password

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am first fetching data from facebook and then I am saving data to parseuser with hardcoded password and below is my code

```
 try
            final ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            parseUser.setUsername(str_email);
            parseUser.setEmail(str_email);
            parseUser.setPassword("loginwithfb3");
            parseUser.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                     @Override
                     public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                          if (e == null) {
                             Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User information saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              loginSuccessful();
                                        } else {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

But i am getting always error like below

```
com.parse.ParseException: Unable to saveEventually on a ParseUser with dirty password
11-04 10:33:21.838 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseUser.validateSaveEventually(ParseUser.java:293)
11-04 10:33:21.838 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1733)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1702)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.example.LoginActivity$2$1.done(LoginActivity.java:309)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.example.LoginActivity$2$1.done(LoginActivity.java:290)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$1.done(ParseTaskUtils.java:74)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$1.done(ParseTaskUtils.java:71)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-04 10:33:21.839 2327-2327/com.example W/System.err:
```

**Unable to saveEventually on a ParseUser with dirty password**

I have changed hardcoded password but nothing happens

Comment: What are you trying to do? After login then you  are saving data(Username and password)?

Answer (score 1):

Try `saveInBackground` instead of `saveEventually`

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
parseUser.setUsername(str_email);
parseUser.setEmail(str_email);
parseUser.setPassword("loginwithfb3");
parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (null == e) {
            //Success
        } else {
            //Failure
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for giving nice suggestion but I want to store this data in off-line (LocalDatabase) also that's why i am using saveEventually

Comment: upvote for your answer but if u could help with saveEventually then please give me suggestion on that